# "paramiko.ChannelException: Administratively prohibited" encountered midway through a script

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm using Python to SSH into a host, run bash commands, and then parse results in a Pythonic way into several data structures for later display.

I'm using the Paramiko library for SSH and executing commands on the remote host like so:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.exec_command("command goes here")
```

I'm running many commands this way and it seems most of them are working (I'm looping through a file and constructing file paths on the remote server to run the commands on). However, about halfway through execution I'm hitting this error.

I think it has something to do with the volume of `ssh.exec_command()` calls I'm making but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have access to (or can you get your hands on the relevant parts of) the sshd logs on the server? Any clues in there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe I've solved it: because `exec_command()` is non-blocking I was essentially trying to run a ton of commands all at once on the remote machine. This was against policy and was blocked.

I worked around this by forcing my script to wait until each command was executed via `stdout.readlines()`. It's working great now.

Comment: Hi ,Can you please explain where to add "stdout.readlines()"?
I am also facing the same issue while executing ton of commands.

Comment: Unfortunately it's been a long time and I don't have the code in question anymore. I think I just added stdout.readlines() (basicaly a blocking no-op, I believe) after each non-blocking command to force each command to finish in series. Obviously this will make things slower.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot ,I have tried and it's working for me now.

Comment: stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(my_command, get_pty=True) \n stdout.readlines() \n I just did like above. It worked.

Answer (score 8):

I have similar problem, and I found there is a SSH server configuration need be modified, too.

Anyone have similar problem can find `"#MaxSessions=10"` in sshd configuration first(In my case, that is `/etc/sshd/sshd_config`).

Modify `MaxSessions=10` to other values may can solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that is actually helpful. Don't forget to  run /bin/systemctl reload sshd.service